# Determining credentials details from Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have two earthengine accounts. One private where I do open-source development and the other one from my company for my day to day job.

I want to use the one that are stored in `~/.config/earthengine/credentials` to connect but impossible to remember if it's the private or company one.

So I connect to ee:

```py
import ee 

ee.Initialize()
```

Is there a way from the `ee` lib to get more information about my current credentials like the connection email?